# Google Image API for QR code application for eclipse android

Tags: android, android-intent, qr-code, zxing, google-visualization

Hear i am working on qrcode generation application development, I am new for EAndroid application development
So can anyone suggest me how i can use google image chart API to integrate it into eclipse android project and use for QR code generation , if any alternatives is there also suggest me that also.

Thank you

Comment: @MAC i have tried to work with intent using zxing but i am not succeed.

Comment: Rephrase your question, I am sure you have specific issue that you are facing with zxing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at "scanning" QR codes then you should try the zxing library. If it gives you trouble there are lot of Q&A on SO to help you out, you can also refer to this [blog](http://mcondev.wordpress.com/category/zxing/).

Search on SO for zxing also [zxing home](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: May I add that zxing is diffcult (some times). Just notice how many questions there are on zxing. Its suppose to be easy, but aint. The Getting Started is tough. So downvoting a question on zxing may be a overkill.

Comment: The OP is asking about encoding, rather than decoding or scanning.

Comment: by this logic "java" must be really really difficult. When a 5-line solution is available, and easily discoverable on Google, you have to wonder why these poor questions like "please make me a whole solution now thanks" still get asked. I didn't down-vote it, but, your logic doesn't justify poor and lazy questions.

Comment: Sure, a google search should have been done before SO.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Intent-based integration described here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Although the page mostly refers to scanning and decoding, the `IntentIntegrator` class actually has a method for encoding data too by Intent.

You don't even need the Google Chart API. But if you do want to use it, there's nothing much to know except that you would display the image that it generates in a `WebView`. That's it.